# Run locust tests sequentially and asynchronously without waiting for response

Tags: asynchronous, post, async-await, httpserver, locust

I want to run locust tests on httpserver post API where the tests should continue to post the request to the service sequentially without waiting for a response from the pending posts.

Let's say there are 2 APIs to be tested. An ordered list of these APIs to be called is provided by the user. Locust should pick the APIs from this list and keep posting to the service without waiting for a response from the previous request.

I created 2 separate tasks for the 2 APIs to be called and added an if-else check on the list to call only the specific APIs from each task. This doesn't guarantee the order of the post request.

Comment: That cant really be done. But you can launch a *really high* number of users and use a constant pacing/throughput wait_time to constrain the throughput.

Comment: Can this be done with some other testing framework?